# MySQL database restore

Tags: bash, mysql

I've written a script which backups my MySQL database and produces
a GZIP file with the mysql dump of my database. I wondered if it's
possible to decompress the GZIP file and restore the database in
one single command?

Something like this:

```
mysql -u user -h host -ppass database < gzip -c database.backup
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

I use the following command:

```
mysqldump -u user -h host -ppass database | gzip -9 > database.backup
```

The error I get is: `-bash: gzip: No such file or directory;` which, in my opinion, indicates that it does not recognise gzip as a command or something like that

Comment: No, it indicates that the `database.backup` file doesn't exist. Are you sure it's there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using two commands so you should use a pipe and not redirection. I use this:

```
gunzip < file.gz | mysql <parameters>
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally this should work. Is gzip installed and available in the PATH-Variable ? (You can test it with command "which gzip"

`mysqldump -u user -h host -ppass database | gzip -9 > database.backup`

but i would use as backup-file the suffix .gz

You also can try

`mysqldump -u user -h host -ppass *--database* "db_name" | gzip -9 > "db_backup".backup.gz`

I wrote a script recently to make a compressed backup of my databases.

http://infofreund.de/easy-mysql-backup/